# Create structures in loop and assign to another structure in IDL

Tags: structure, variable-assignment, idl

In IDL I would like to create a structure in a loop with different data and then to assign them all to the main structure that will zip everything.
I tried to used an array of structures, but I am stopped because I am not able to assign to the main structure:

```
alarm_list = { rg : 0, rf : 4}

alarm = { $  
          Alarm_Id : 0 , $  
          Range :      1, $
          Bin : 0        $ 
        }

arr = REPLICATE(alarm, 4)  
FOR ia = 0, 3 DO BEGIN
    alarm.alarm_id = ia
    alarm.bin = bin
    arr[ia] = alarm
    bin += 1
ENDFOR
```

I would like to assign all 4 alarms with different names (i.e. alarm1 = , alarm2 = ...) to the main "alarm_list".
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something along these lines, assigning to the array directly instead of using the alarm variable as an intermediate:

```
alarm_list= REPLICATE({alarm, Alarm_Id:0, Range:1, Bin:0},4)

FOR ia = 0, 3 DO BEGIN
    alarm_list[i].alarm_id = ia
    alarm_list[i].bin = bin
    bin += 1
ENDFOR
```

Hope this helps guide.